# how to .replaceAll the sign "( "

Tags: java, replaceall

I have a code like this

```
public class New {
public static void main(String args[]) {
String s1 = "( Hey!! You're my everything )";
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("(","buka kurung"); 
System.out.print(replaceString); 
}
}
```

i wanna replace that `(` to `buka kurung` but error.

Comment: You do it by learning [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and apply what you learned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape '(' to literally mean it. You can do so by '\('

```
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("\\(","buka kurung");
```